# Broken pipe with jpa 2.1, Hibernate 4.3.7 and C3P0

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, c3p0

I have a problem of broken pipe in my software. I'm using Hibernate 4.3.7 and JPA 2.1 Final along with C3P0, I've tried everything, but still giving broken pipe when the time expires MySQL.

Logs from tomcat:

```
ERROR: The last packet successfully received from the server was 57,069,477 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 57,069,477 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
Nov 06, 2014 8:27:23 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: #{controleLogin.efetuarLogin()}: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
javax.faces.FacesException: #{controleLogin.efetuarLogin()}: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    at br.com.clikyapp1.modelo.UsuarioDAO.login(UsuarioDAO.java:26)
    at br.com.clikyapp1.controle.ControleLogin.efetuarLogin(ControleLogin.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 57,069,477 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 57,069,477 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1137)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2596)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2840)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2212)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3964)
    ... 60 more

Nov 06, 2014 8:27:23 AM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
SEVERE: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    at br.com.clikyapp1.modelo.UsuarioDAO.login(UsuarioDAO.java:26)
    at br.com.clikyapp1.controle.ControleLogin.efetuarLogin(ControleLogin.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 57,069,477 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 57,069,477 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1137)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2596)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2840)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2212)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3964)
    ... 60 more
```

Here is my persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="clikyapp1">

    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Cultura</class>
    <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Cidade</class>
    <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Estado</class>
    <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.TipoDespesa</class>
    <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Safra</class>
    <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.TipoContrato</class>
    <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Area</class>
    <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Armazem</class>
    <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Conta</class>
    <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Parceiro</class>
    <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Usuario</class>
    <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Contrato</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="senha" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clikyapp1" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
            value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="100" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="3" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statement" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="select 1;" />

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.interactive_timeout" value="10" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.connect_timeout" value="20" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

any idea?

Comment: JSF is a framework that, in the end, generates HTML. It is unrelated to service and data access layer and it's not tied to the database engine you use at all.

Comment: Looks like your problem is in the configuration of C3P0. I would recommend posting your C3P0 configuration or to migrate to another database connection pool provider like BoneCP (deprecated in favour of HikariCP).

Comment: Well, did you set `autoReconnect=true` as suggested by the error message?

Answer (score 0):

1) There's a typo in your c3p0 config.

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statement" value="50" />
```

should be

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
```

2) In

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="select 1;" />
```

...get rid of the semicolon. That is, just...

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="select 1" />
```

3) These two properties are not valid c3p0 configuration:

```
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.interactive_timeout" value="10" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.connect_timeout" value="20" />
```

It looks like you are trying to set mysql server properties. `interactive_timout` is irrelevant; it is a config param for mysql command line tools. `connect_timout` (and `wait_timeout`) are [system variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html) you can [set on the server side](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html)

4) Verify that the config you want is the config c3p0 is actually seeing. c3p0 dumps its config at INFO on pool initialization. Look at that.

5) Assuming the configuration you intend has got through, you haven't quite got a reliable test regime configured. You are frequently testing idle Connections, but in theory a busy pool might never leave Connections idle for long enough to be tested. Given that MySQL is complaining about a disused rather than busy Connection, this is unlikely to be your problem. But still, it'd be good to [impose a better testing regime](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing), by, for example, setting `testConnectionOnCheckin` to `true`.

6) Once you get your config right, if you still see the error, the likely cause is that your application is holding onto Connections for long periods of time (e.g. as member variables) rather than checking them out as-necessary and close()ing them immediately. That's a bad idea. c3p0 can't help keep your Connections fresh if your application keeps them checked out, and the point of a Connection pool is to eliminate the performance cost of just-in-time Connection checkout. So, fix that.

If you aren't sure or don't think that any Connections are held open for long periods of time by your application, you can use the two settings `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces`. The first will cause any Connections held open by your client application by more than the number of seconds configured to be forceably returned to the pool. The second will cause the stack trace of the code that checkout out the bad Connection to be dumped into log. See [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients).